# Is there such a thing as "combinatorial category theory"?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

According to wikipedia,

> In mathematics, combinatorial group theory is the theory of free groups, and the concept of a presentation of a group by generators and relations

Is there such a thing as "combinatorial category theory"? (a theory of free categories and presentation of categories, by a directed graph and relations)

I googled a bit and couldn't find anything interesting.

I thought about the would be analogue for the Nielsen-Schereir theorem, but it fails (for monoids!).

Comment: Please, don't get me started on that "category theory" thing...combinatorial category theory, too!

Comment: Category theorists tend not to study small categories like that... to the extent that, lately, some have taken to calling the locally presentable categories of Gabriel and Ulmer simply as "presentable categories" – despite the fact that they are "presentable" only in a sense that is very far from the sense in which groups are "presentable"!

Comment: Thanks. And do you know if anybody is interested in studying small categories in that way?

Comment: To some extent, the methods developed to define and study various kinds of higher categories may qualify as `combinatorial category theory'. You might have a look at, e.g., the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0617) by Lafont, Métayer, and Worytkiewicz on polygraphs/computads and strict $\omega$-categories, or Weber's work on functors with arities. For the latter, the best paper to start with may be [the one with Berger and Melliès](https://sites.google.com/site/markwebersmaths/home/monads-with-arities).